# nodejs how to print console that sticks on top

Tags: node.js, console-application, command-line-interface, console.log

lets say i want to make

sometime like linux or unix TOP using nodejs.

example

```
EXMPLE APP

ram usage : 30MB
processor usage : 20%

// above this line refreshed and but a fixed position
---------- LOGS ------------
// below this line is refreshed and max last 5 console.logs

example : server down at x
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
```

so the screen wont go down so

```
// missing ram usage and processor usage as the page go down
example : server down at x
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at x
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
example : server down at y
```

where do i start?, is there any good tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top in Linux is implemented using the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) library. There's a project providing Node.js bindings for ncurses here: https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses

Answer (score 1):

If you want a native solution, try [charm](https://github.com/substack/node-charm), but it's definitely less powerful then ncurses.